# How to load Bootstrap scripts in environment that might have them already?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use popover (and its tooltip dependency) script from Bootstrap in my WordPress plugin.

It is likely that plugin will land in environments that already have Bootstrap and I am trying to determine how to implement this in robust way.

1. I could try to check for plugin definitions and dynamically load scripts if they are not present (otherwise use what environment has). However timing seems challenging since one of scripts depends on another and having plugins of same name loaded doesn't guarantee it is compatible version or even Bootstrap script at all.
2. Scripts seem to include `noConflict()` functionality, which I could try to use to stash away my own copies and ignore presence of global ones in any case. However again I am not sure how to get mechanics of this right, since popover needs tooltip to work. Also from looking through Bootstrap issue tracker later  it seems that `noConflict()` in tooltips is currently broken and will be only fixed in v3. :(
3. It seems like additional loader (such as yepnope) could deal with this for me, but it feels like digging myself deeper into a hole.

Which of these (or other than these) methods would be practical to implement?

Comment: Do you have control over the other environments? If that is the case, I would look into something like RequireJS.

Comment: @moderndegree no control (publicly available WP plugin) or it would be non-issue... As per (3) I started to look at loaders, but it's challenging for my JS chops (things like - "if loader controls scripts not to conflict, what controls loader itself not to conflict..."  rabbit hole).

Comment: That makes things more challenging. Unfortunately, I don't think there will be a way to know which version of Bootstrap is loaded, as it doesn't have an API for that. You could attempt to enclose your version of bootstrap as to not interfere with any global instance.

Comment: @moderndegree elaborate on "enclose" please?

Comment: In RequireJS you could wrap bootstrap with something like this: define(['jquery'], function(){
});

Comment: perhaps I can jsfiddle something

Answer (score 1):

Use RequireJS to load in your own scripts and wrap them with some closure.

```
// let's say tooltip was defined already
$.fn.tooltip = function(data){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        console.log(data.title);
    });
};

// we'll apply the old tooltip to .tooltip1
$('.tooltip1').tooltip({
    title: 'tada',
    placement: 'bottom'
});

// what version of jquery did we have out here
console.log($.fn.jquery);

require({
    "paths": {
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min",
      "bootstrap": "//twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$.fn.tooltip'
        }
    }
}, ['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($){
    // what version of jquery do we have in here
    console.log($.fn.jquery);

    // now we apply the bootstrap tooltip to .tooltip2
    $('.tooltip2').tooltip({
        title: 'tada',
        placement: 'bottom'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/prSUF/

Comment: I need to read up on RequireJS to get the mechanics there but fiddle does seem to demonstrate isolation working. Quick question - essentially this can be implemented without loader, right? It hit me that plugin registers in jQuery object so essentially it can be seen as matter of giving it separate jQuery object to live in. However not sure if I can have two objects of same jQuery version technically...

Comment: You can definitely do two versions of jQuery. Read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

You should be able to accomplish most of what you want with that.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can have two _different_ versions, I was wondering if I can have two objects of _same_ version from same script. Basically have jQuery (bundled in WP) loaded once, but have a separate object for only Bootstrap scripts to run on. Will be experimenting and will update later.